# R: nel2igraph and PN.amalgamation - igraph not correctly produced

Tags: r, igraph, shapefile

I encounter a problem with the package `shp2graph`. I want to use the function `PN.amalgamation` which works fine (see below). Afterwards, I would like to create an igraph object. Here the code fails to do that. 
I can create igraph objects just fine with every non-amalgamated shp2graph object.

Here my sample code, which largely is a copy paste from the description of the package `shp2graph`:

```
library(igraph)
library(shp2graph)

data(ORN)
rtNEL<-readshpnw(ORN.nt, ELComputed=TRUE)
res.sl<-SL.extraction(rtNEL[[2]],rtNEL[[3]])
res.me<-ME.simplification(res.sl[[1]],res.sl[[2]],DegreeL=res.sl[[4]]) 
res.pn<-PN.amalgamation(res.me[[1]],res.me[[2]],DegreeL=res.me[[4]])
ptcoords<-Nodes.coordinates(res.pn[[1]])
plot(ORN.nt)
points(ptcoords, col="green")
plot(ORN.nt)
points(Nodes.coordinates(rtNEL[[2]]), col="red")

# igraph created from amalgamation is wrong
test <- nel2igraph(nodelist= res.pn[[1]], edgelist=res.pn[[2]], Directed = TRUE)
plot(test,vertex.size=1,edge.width=1,edge.arrow.size=0,vertex.label=NA)

# res.me is one step before amalgamation
test <- nel2igraph(nodelist= res.me[[1]], edgelist=res.me[[2]], Directed = TRUE)
plot(test,vertex.size=1,edge.width=1,edge.arrow.size=0,vertex.label=NA)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the bug lies somehow in the interaction with the `igraph` package. The issue is that the labels of the nodes create by `PN.amalgamation` are not continuous anymore; some are missing, since we deleted them. However, `igraph` somehow still tries to create them and gives then the following warning:

For anyone having the same trouble here a work-around, which re-indeces the labels.

Create your own `nel2igraph` function:

```
nel2igraph_corr <- function (nodelist, edgelist, weight = NULL, eadf = NULL, Directed = FALSE) 
{


  nodes <- nodelist[, 1]
  Ne <- length(edgelist[, 1])
  Nn <- length(nodes)

    for (i in 1:Nn) {
      kk <- nodelist[i,][[1]]
      edgelist[which(edgelist[,c(2)]==kk),2] <- i
      edgelist[which(edgelist[,c(3)]==kk),3] <- i

      nodelist[i,][[1]] <- i
  }

    if (!is.null(weight)) {
    if (length(weight) != Ne && is.numeric(weight)) 
      stop("Please give right edge weight, which must be numeric and the same length as edges elment")
  }
  if (!is.null(eadf)) {
    if (length(eadf[, 1]) != Ne) 
      stop("The eadf must be numeric and the same length as edges elment")
  }



  gr <- graph.edgelist(unique(edgelist[, c(2, 3)]), directed = T)
  gr <- set.vertex.attribute(gr, "x", V(gr), Nodes.coordinates(nodelist)[,1])
  gr <- set.vertex.attribute(gr, "y", V(gr), Nodes.coordinates(nodelist)[, 
                                                                         2])
  gr.es <- E(gr)
  if (!is.null(weight)) 
    gr <- set.edge.attribute(gr, "weight", gr.es, weight)
  if (!is.null(eadf)) {
    eanms <- colnames(eadf)
    n <- length(eanms)
    for (i in 1:n) gr <- set.edge.attribute(gr, eanms[i], 
                                            gr.es, eadf[, i])
  }
  gr
}
```